# Fullcalendar change day interval from 00:00-23:59 to 07:00-06:59

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using the fullcalendar plugin and would like to modify the agendaWeek type display days from 07:00-06:59 instead of 00:00-23:59.

With

> minTime: '07:00'

I can get the day to start at 07:00 but maxTime won't make the day last longer than 23:59.

Is there any simple solution to this problem?

Comment: There is no such option in fullcalendar, unfortunately. I believe there is no simple solution for this either.

Comment: @A1rPun I was afraid so. Thanks for your answer.