# It is possible to change the layout of fullcalendar from 00:00:00 - 23:59:00 to 19:00:00 - 06:59:00?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Good day, can any-one solved this problem?

I want to change the layout of the internval time from 00:00:00 - 23:59:00 to 19:00:00 - 06:59:00?
The reason is for the night shift peeps out there. haha.

I saw same question [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893169/fullcalendar-change-day-interval-from-0000-2359-to-0700-0659), and the answer is not possible. But that is 4years ago.

I hope there's a solution for this in v4 of fullcalendar.

Comment: No, there's still no solution - the timeGrid view is still built on the same assumption, that it covers a period within a single day. I haven't tried but you _might_ be able to make it work using the (more flexible) `timeline` view, and the `visibleRange` setting. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view-no-resources, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/visibleRange

Comment: P.S. changed your tags because fullCalendar 4 is not written as a jquery plugin anymore :-)

Comment: No problem. If you make it work using timeline view, maybe post your answer here so others can benefit from the idea :-) (you are allowed to answer your own question!)

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative solution for this.

I just add min and max time for the calendar option.

```
minTime: '18:00:00',
maxTime: '30:00:00',
```

so the output will be from 6:00 pm to 7:00 am

note:
just add your `mintime` by how many hours you want your calendar will be.

In my example. i just want my calendar be 6pm to 7am therefore i will just my `minTime(18:00)` by 13 hours therefore the input for `maxTime` will be `30:00`

see below image for the result:

[image: Calendar view]

I hope this will help others.

also correct me if this is a bad practice for this problem. 
:) thank you